# why class init method get run in dict.get?

Tags: python, class

```
class Case:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print('init class instance')
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Case(fn={self.name})'


d = {'a': Case('fn')}
d.get('a', Case('bbb'))
```

why the **init** method was called twice?
the get method should find that key a already exists, and ignore the default part altogether.

Comment: Expressions are fully evaluated before the object is passed as a parameter. The `.get` function is ignoring the parameter, but that object was already created in *the caller*

Comment: and how to avoid it?

Comment: The most straightforward way, don't use `.get`. Check if key is in dict, if not, create the object.